# Algebra system of equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve this system of equation?

$$\begin{align*}&.05(w+2000)=.03(y+3000)\\
&4w=\frac{y}2+500
\end{align*}$$

I end up setting them up like this but I am not sure if it is correct.

$$\begin{align*}&5w-3y=-10\\
&-2w-y=500
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

The first one expands to $0.05w+100=0.03y+90$, which you can rewrite as $0.05w-0.03y=-10$; if you want to get rid of the decimals, you’ll need to multiply **both** sides by $100$, and you’ll get $5w-3y=-1000$. You made a similar error in manipulating the second equation: if you multiply both sides by $2$ to get rid of the fraction, you should have $2w=y+1000$. You forgot to multiply the $500$ by $2$. You also made a sign error in getting both variables on the same side of the equation. Can you see now what it ought to be?

Answer (score 1):

It's off a bit.

For the first equation,
$$
.05(w+2000) = .03(y+3000)
$$
do the multiplications first, using the distributive law:
$$
.05 w +100 =.03 y +90.
$$
Rewrite this a bit to get
$$
\tag{1} .05 w-.03 y=-10.
$$

For the second equation
$$
w={y\over 2}+500,
$$
multiply both sides by 2 (so multiply each term by 2) to get
$$
2w=y+1000.
$$
Rewrite this a bit to get
$$\tag{2}
2w-y=1000.
$$

So, your system becomes
$$
\eqalign{
.05 w-.03 y&=-10\cr 2w-y&=1000.
}
$$

Comment: i got w=4000 I think that is correct thanks for the help

Comment: @ElCholo That is correct. $w=4000$ (and  $y=7000$).